# Tell iOS to show Passcode view in Dark Theme?

Tags: ios, security, authentication, uikit, touch-id

My iOS app has an option to require authentication using passcode or Touch ID.  When they choose to enter a passcode the view shows white.  I know there is a dark theme passcode entry because my iPhone 6S running iOS 9.x starts with a dark theme.  Is it possible from my app to tell iOS to show the password/passcode view in a dark theme instead of white?

```
LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthentication
```